# Stack Overflow downvote question improvement

Tags: discussion, questions, down-votes

I recently asked a few questions on Stack Overflow, however most of them got at least one downvote or no upvote (at the time of checking). Despite I have autistic conditions and English isn't my first language, could anyone please help me to analyze on what has been flawed, and how could I improve for better?

Here are the links to my questions:

[The most recent one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42598637/javascript-drag-and-drop-html-div-sections)

[Slightly older one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41079458/oracle-generate-thumbnail-based-on-stored-ordimage)

Can you suggest any improvement advice?

Comment: First, this should probably be on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com), as it's specific to [so].  Second, the second question seems ok to me. I don't think it's gotten many views, there's not really any specific reason it's bad or wrong.

Comment: Well, on the recent one, you have a requirement, but no code.  This has a 'do my work for me' smell.  Also, 'What is the most efficient way to achieve this' has a reek of asking for an opinion: 'efficient' is not defined.

Comment: OK. I learned. Thanks for your replies!

Comment: Your English is okay. There are some rules on the site, they will say them for you. Particularly new usersstart with a big backwind. A lot of them have a longstanding fight for the entry in the group of the literate people. All of them are pretty good in your case. So don't worry.

Comment: Note: you can collect reputation *much faster* if you give also answers, not only questions. 1) for an answer upvote you get 10 rep, for a question only 5 2) people likes much more to vote for answers.